# Blocked asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I have an XHR asynchronous call in an embedded environment that seems to be blocking my UI. The calls seem to be blocked only when they involve DNS resolution, but not otherwise. So, when I try to query http://www.google.com, the call blocks; but when I query "http://173.194.39.18", it doesn't. My understanding is that if the environment has an IP address but no DNS resolution capability (as in the case where your device has a network connection to a router, but the router itself is not connected to the Internet), then the call gets blocked for the duration of the DNS timeout.

Is this correct, or am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 0):

A DNS timeout will be very much like a regular timeout.  Although, due to this being an asynchronous call this should not "block" any other function (unless it is waiting for a success event).

If you need to shorten this time you can set a timeout for the request.

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send-method

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help for two reasons:
a. the 'timeout' attribute hasn't been implemented - AFAIK - in current production versions of most JS engines.
b. I did mention that the timeouts seem to happen only for requests that require DNS resolution, not others.